# Calling a Method That Takes a Parameter Within ActionListener

Tags: java, parameters, actionlistener

I've encountered a problem while trying to call a method within a class that implements `actionListener`. The method being called, `DataCompiler`, needs to use the integer `wordCountWhole`, which is returned in the `wordCount` class. The problem is that I can't pass the required parameter to the `actionListener method`.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.List;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
 import java.text.BreakIterator;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.stream.IntStream;

 public class GUI extends JFrame {
     public JTextArea textInput;
     public JButton dataButton;
     public String str;

     public GUI() {
         super("Text Miner");
         pack();
         setLayout(null);

         dataButton = new JButton("View Data"); //Button to take user to data table
         dataButton.setSize(new Dimension(120, 50));
         dataButton.setLocation(5, 5);
         Handler event = new Handler(); //Adds an action listener to each button
         dataButton.addActionListener(event);
         add(dataButton);

         public class wordCount {
             public int miner() {
                 //This returns an integer called wordCountWhole
             }
         }

         public class Handler implements Action { //All the possible actions for when an action is observed

             public void action(ActionEvent event, int wordCountWhole) {

                 if (event.getSource() == graphButton) {
                     Graphs g = new Graphs();
                     g.Graphs();
                 } else if (event.getSource() == dataButton) {
                     DataCompiler dc = new DataCompiler();
                     dc.Data(wordCountWhole);
                 } else if (event.getSource() == enterButton) {
                     wordCount wc = new wordCount();
                     sentenceCount sc = new sentenceCount();
                     wc.miner();
                     sc.miner();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

And here's the code for the DataCompiler class:

```
public class DataCompiler{
    public void Data(int wordCountWhole){
        int m = wordCountWhole;
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add the parameter there because you've invalidated the contract of the interface.

Use a constructor* (see note below, first)

```
public class Handler implements Action{ //All the possible actions for when an action is observed

    private int wordCountWhole;

    public Handler(int number) { this.wordCountWhole = number; } 

    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
```

---

**Although**, it isn't entirely clear why you need that number. Your `DataCompiler.Data` method just prints the number passed into it, and that variable seemingly comes from nowhere in your code because it is not passed to the ActionListener.

`*` You should instead use `Integer.parseInt(textInput.getText().trim())` inside Handler class / the listener code and not use a constructor. Otherwise, you'd always get the number value when you add the Handler, which would be an empty string and throw an error because the text area has no number in it.

Additionally, `wc.miner();` returns a value, but calling it on its own without assigning it to a number just throws away that return value.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding! I followed your advice and all seems well until it comes to running the program, then it throws an error telling me that "The constructor GUI.Handler() is undefined", so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I've only been programming in Java for about two months, so I'm still getting to grips with it. Do you want me to post my revised code?

Comment: The second half of my answer explains that you should not use a constructor because you shouldn't pass the integer to the listener at all.

Comment: Maybe I should have better explained that I need that integer to do some data analysis, and the DataCompiler class is going to be comparing different values and printing those to the screen, rather than just the original integer. I can't work out how to call the DataCompiler method without this integer being passed to the actionlistener. Sorry~

Comment: And I explained you get the EditText input **inside** the listener rather than pass an integer because otherwise, the integer never changes. Please explain why you are unable to obtain the number inside the listener rather than passing it in

Comment: Ah, okay! It makes sense now, sorry for being a bit slow off the mark. The solution doesn't look very elegant, but I need it to work more than look nice, so thank you very much! :)